# Simple example of Multiprocessing and multi-threading

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have the following code:

```
class SplunkUKAnalyser(object):

    def __init__
    def method1
    def method2
    def method2
    ...

class SplunkDEAnalyser(SplunkUKAnalyser):

    def __init__    (Over-ridden)
    def method1     (Over-ridden)
    def method2
    def method2
    ...

perform_uk_analysis():
    my_uk_analyser = SplunkUKAnalyser() 

perform_de_analysis():
    my_de_analyser = SplunkDEAnalyser()
```

It all works well if I just execute the below:

```
perform_uk_analysis()
perform_de_analysis()
```

How can I make it so that the two last statements are executed concurrently. (using mutliprocessing and/or multi-threading)?

From my test it seems that the second statement executes even though the first statement has not finished completely but I would like to incorporate true concurrency.

Any other additional advice is much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of [GIL (Global Interpreter Lock)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) you can not achieve 'true concurrency' with `threading`.

However, using `multiprocessing` to concurrently run multiple tasks is easy:

```
import multiprocessing

process1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=perform_uk_analysis)
process2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=perform_de_analysis)
# you can optionally daemoize the process
process2.daemon = True
# run the tasks concurrently
process1.start()
process2.start()
# you can optionally wait for a process to finish
process2.join()
```

For tasks that run the same function with different arguments, consider using `multiprocessing.Pool`, an even more convenient solution.

Comment: Thanks, What properties/limitations do daemonized processes have?

Comment: I tried this but it looks like the second object creation still does not occur i.e. the "perform_de_analysis".

Basically each of the above methods perform_de_analysis() and perform_uk_analysis() log into two different (one in UK and one in Germany) Splunk syslog servers and perform a whole bunch of searches one by one. It seems as though the UK module has to finish before the DE one starts. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe there is some dependency between the 2 functions. Without seeing the code I don't know where to start... But one possibility is that there is some shared resource used by both functions, and one process has to release it before the other can use it?

Comment: Cheers thanks for your help, will look into it further.